# Showing that if $f(\bar{E}) = \overline f(E)$ then $f$ is continous.

Tags: general-topology

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a function between topological spaces $X$ and $Y$. I am trying to show that if for any $E\subseteq X$ we have $f(\bar{E}) \subseteq \overline {f(E)}$ then $f$ is continous.

My book says the following: let $x\in X$ and then let $V$ be an open nhood of $f(x)$. Set $E = X - f^{-1}(V)$ and $U = X - \bar{E}$. Then $x\in U$ and $f(U)\subseteq V$ and then we are done.

However I am struggling to see how $x\in U$ how can I show this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note $$f(x) \in V \implies x \in f^{-1}(V) \implies x \notin E \implies x \notin \overline E \implies x \in U$$
because $E = X- f^{-1}(V)$ and $U = X - \overline E$.

Comment: how do we know $x \notin \bar{E}$?

Comment: That is the hypothesis $f(\overline E) \subset \overline{f(E)}$. If $x \in \overline E$ then $f(x) \in \overline{f(E)}$, contrary to the fact $f(x)$ is interior to $V$.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you have
$x\in f^{-1}(V)$ by definition, that means that $x\notin E$ as it is $X$ minus the inverse image, that means that $x\notin \bar{E}$ which then means it is in the complement of $\bar{E}$, which is $U$.

Comment: $x$ could not be in $E$ while still being in the closure

Answer (score 0):

If $x\notin U,$ then $x\in \overline E$ so as $f(\overline E)\subseteq \overline {f(E)}, $ every neighborhood of $f(x)$ intersects $f(E).$ But by construction $V\cap f(E)=\emptyset.$ Contradiction. So $x\in U$.

I think it's easier to show continuity the way Munkres does it:

Suppose $B$ is closed in $Y$. Then, if $A=f^{-1}(B)$ we have $f(A)=f(f^{-1}(B))\subseteq B$ where the last inclusion is true by simple set theory. Then noting that $B=\overline B,$ we take an $x\in \overline A$ and compute:

$f(x)\in f(\overline A)\subseteq \overline {f(E)}\subset \overline B=B.$

This shows that $x\in f^{-1}(B)=A$ which now implies that $\overline A\subseteq A$ so in fact $A$ is closed and so $f$ is continuous.